# Firebase asks for my app's bundle ID, but I didn't create my app with Xcode so I have none -- how should I make one, or what do I submit?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to link my React Native iOS app with Firebase, and the first thing Firebase asks for is a bundle ID, which it says I can get from Xcode's "General" tab. However, I didn't make this app with Xcode; I made it in a Node.js environment with the `create-react-native-app` command, so it seems I don't have a bundle identifier. Unless I do? How can I proceed to link my app to Firebase?

Comment: Just open the project in Xcode.You can find a bundle identifier there

Comment: @VinayakB unfortunately XCode says it can't open this directory; it looks like it's looking for a specific kind of file, and a normal directory won't cut it

Answer (score 1):

To get your bundle Id run following steps:

Open Xcode -> File/Open -> find your RN project -> open folder "ios" -> open top file of your project -> find section "Identity" -> copy "Bundle Identifier" which probably will be like: `org.reactjs.native.example.[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]`

You are good to go.